# sql store procedures

Tags: sql-server-2005, copying

i want to copy store procedures from one database to other database with different servers.. may i know how

Comment: how many are there?

Answer (score 1):

This link should give you the answer you're looking for. Just scroll down a little.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/13042-how-copy-stored-procedures-from-one-database.aspx